# Combine codebind css class and page css class in asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have asp:label tag, in which I bind css class

```
<asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="<%# LabelCssClass %>" Text="Number" AssociatedControlID="txtNumber" />
```

When I try to add other class in aspx page, like

```
<asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="<%# LabelCssClass %> myclass" Text="Number" AssociatedControlID="txtNumber" />
```

In html page I got this

> class="<%# LabelCssClass %> myclass"

My question is: is this possible to combine two types of declaring classes? Or should I use only one? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to using like this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="<%=LabelCssClass%> myclass" Text="Number" AssociatedControlID="txtNumber" />
```